# Looking up a column value from a DataFrame of DataFrame objects

Tags: python, pandas

The actual problem is more complex, so this is a simplified version.
I have 2 DataFrames.
data_A is a regular DataFrame.
data_B is a DataFrame of DataFrames, with the column 'data C' containing other DataFrames data_C1 and data_C2. Note that column_B only contains unique values in 'Column 1'. This is our lookup table.

```
data_A = {'Column 1': [2, 2, 3],
          'Column 2': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
          'Column 3': [20, 30, 30]}
data_B = {'Column 1': [2, 3],
          'data C': [data_C1, data_C2]}

data_C1 = {'Limit': [20,30], 'Value': [0.2, 0.3]}
data_C2 = {'Limit': [20,30], 'Value': [0.3, 0.4]}
```

I want to iterate through each row in data_A, using the values of data_A['Column 1'] and match it to data_B['Column 1'] and get the corresponding 'data C' column. Then take the data_A['Column 3'] and match it to the resulting dataframe's 'Limit' column, and add the 'Value' to data_A.

Basically, I want to get the 'Value' in data_C on the condition that data_A['Column 1'] = data_B['Column 1'] and data_A['Column 3'] = data_C['Limit']

Desire output:

```
| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |  Value   |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
|    2     |    A     |    20    |    0.2   |
|    2     |    B     |    20    |    0.3   |
|    3     |    C     |    30    |    0.4   |
```

```
# Create DataFrames A and B
data_A = {'Column 1': [2, 2, 3],
          'Column 2': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
          'Column 3': [10, 20, 30]}

data_C1 = {'Head 1': [{'Limit': 20, 'Value': 0.2}, {'Limit': 30, 'Value': 0.3}]}
data_C2 = {'Head 1': [{'Limit': 20, 'Value': 0.2}, {'Limit': 30, 'Value': 0.3}]}


df_A = pd.DataFrame(data_A)
df_C1 = pd.DataFrame(data_C1)
df_C2 = pd.DataFrame(data_C2)

data_B = {'Column 1': [2, 3],
          'data C obj': [data_C1, data_C2]}

df_B = pd.DataFrame(data_B)

# Merge DataFrames on 'Column 1'
merged_df = df_A.merge(df_B, on='Column 1', how='left')
```

This is where I got stuck. This is probably not an elegant approach, as I only want the final value. If there's a method that can avoid the merge I would gladly use it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution:

To achieve the desired output, we'll perform the following operations sequentially:

1. Merge `data_A` and `data_B`, using `"Column 1"` as key.
2. Create a new column called `"Limit"` that contains a list of possible limits from merged column `"data C"` for each row.
3. Apply the same logic from previous step to create a new column `"Value"`.
4. Use the method `pandas.DataFrame.explode`, to transform each element of a list-like to a row, replicating index values.
5. Filter rows that have `"Limit"` values equal to `"Column 3"`.
6. Drop (remove) unnecessary columns.

We can implement all the steps listed above without the need for intermediary dataframes, by defining them in a method-chain style:

```py
output = (
    data_A.merge(data_B, on="Column 1")
    .assign(Limit=lambda pdf: pdf["data C"].apply(lambda row: row["Limit"]).values.tolist())
    .assign(Value=lambda pdf: pdf["data C"].apply(lambda row: row["Value"]).values.tolist())
    .explode(column=["Limit", "Value"])
    .loc[lambda pdf: pdf["Limit"] == pdf["Column 3"]]
    .drop(columns=["data C", "Limit"])
)
```

**Result:**

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | A | 20 | 0.2 |
| 2 | B | 30 | 0.3 |
| 3 | C | 30 | 0.4 |

Comment: Thanks! The explode function is something I didn't know about, that's quite useful!